# How to include many fields in data projection for Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We are currently limiting the fields returned under some but not all (based on permissions) MongoDB queries using syntax like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

Query query = new Query();
query.fields()
          .include("field1")
          .include("field2")
          .include("field3")
          .include("field4");
```

Unfortunately we have quite a few fields and was wondering if there was a better way of approaching this? The query object eventually gets passed to a mongoTemplate instance for execution against the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass the projection stage because If you create a POJO of the required object (after the projection) it will happen automaticaly...

For example we have class that called Petrucci:

```
@Data //<--- I highly recommand to use lombok
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Petrucci {
 int f1;
 int f2;
 int f3;
}
```

Then when you run :

```
Petrucci john = mongoTemplate.findOne(
  Query.query(Criteria.where("f1").is("majesty")), Petrucci.class);
```

The projection will happen auto and only the fields of the Petrucci class will be left.